# Cookies aren't always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have the following script:

```
function dsm_setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function dsm_getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}

jQuery(window).ready(function() {
  var fontsize = dsm_getCookie('class-fontsize');
  jQuery('body').prepend(fontsize); // Debug
  if (fontsize == 1) {
    jQuery('body').addClass('fontsize');
  }

  jQuery('.fontsize-small').click(function() {
    if (jQuery('body').hasClass('fontsize')) {
      jQuery('body').removeClass('fontsize');
    }
    dsm_setCookie('class-fontsize', 0, 30);
  });

  jQuery('.fontsize-large').click(function() {
    if (!jQuery('body').hasClass('fontsize')) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('fontsize');
    }
    dsm_setCookie('class-fontsize', 1, 30);
  });
});
```

Here I made an example on jsfiddle, which is working as it should.
https://jsfiddle.net/9wdqp161/

Now, when I add the script to my wordpress, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I've been trying to figure it for days, but I can't seem to find what is causing it.

Comment: use proper brackets at `while`

Comment: Hmm, gonna try that. Although I just copied the cookie script from w3.

Comment: @UnknownUser Doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use local storage instead of cookie that is far better than this. and very easy also. e.g. `localStorage.setItem('firstname', 'kaushik');` and `localStorage.getItem('firstname');`

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna look into localStorage now :)

Comment: @UnknownUser Works like a charm and even saves code, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative

[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

You can use local storage instead of `cookie` and very easy to use.

e.g.

```
localStorage.setItem('firstname', 'kaushik'); 
localStorage.getItem('firstname');
// output - kaushik
```

Answer (score 0):

While using cookie, you need to take care of below points:

- Do not exceed more than 50 cookies per domain.
- Maximum limit of cookies is around 4k per domain. i.e. the size of
  all cookies should not exceed 4k. This means you can have 1 cookie of
  4k or 2 cookies of 2k etc.

This may help you.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I've reached the limit yet. Wouldn't this make it stop working in any way? Cause sometimes it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding a `path` to your cookie definition in `dsm_setCookie()`:

```
document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';' + expires + ';path=/';
```

It's possible that the cookie is defaulting to the current path of the current document location...which may not be the root of your site.

Comment: Tried changing the code with your snippet. No luck so far. It's weird that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.